# How with QueryDSL get the map of ids of one entity and the numbers of associated entities

Tags: java, querydsl

How to get the map of ids of one entity (key) and the numbers of associated entities (value). Without transfer entities.
Something like this:

```
from(qE1)
   .join(qE2).on(qE2.qE1_id.eq(qE1.id))
   .where(qE1_exp)
   .transform(GroupBy.groupBy(qE2.id).as(qE1.count())) // ?
```

QueryDSL-4.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert with QueryDSL but I believe something like this or similar using JPAQueryFactory could do it.

```
Map<Long, Long> entityMap = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
.select(qE2.qE1.id, qE2.count())
.from(qE2)
.join(qE2.qE1)
.where(qE1_exp)
.groupBy(qE2.qE1.id)
.fetch()
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
    tuple -> tuple.get(qE2.qE1.id),
    tuple -> tuple.get(qE2.count())
));
```